# Ingesting SSE (server-sent events) in azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, server-sent-events

I am trying to convert a third-party [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) based API to a web hook based API.

The idea is to listen to the event stream and only call the web hook for events of interest.

I've looked at Azure Functions (and Azure Durable Functions), but it isn't clear if it is possible to ingest an SSE event stream as a trigger.

How would I go about listening to such an event stream and sending the event data to (one or more) Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to react on particular type of event, then it's not the right choice (unless you put some if statement in your functions).

You'd better send the SSE to an Azure Event Hub, and use Stream Analytics to query in real time your stream and send the event's you want to your Azure function.

Comment: What if I just forward the data through to a webhook? The issue I have is simply "subscribing" to the SSE. I can't figure out how to do that with functions or durable functions (or, for that matter on event hub)

Comment: You will need to use SignalR binding for example. Then, for processing you can use Durable or not. It will depends on what needs to be done.